# Texto como formato archivo

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

buen día.

Estoy trabajando en un chat interno en un sistema. Y le meti un input donde se pudiera agregar archivos para enviar. pero cuando selecciono el archivo y envió el mensaje con el archivo, me lo muestra como texto y no como archivo.

Y quiero poder que cuando se abra el chat, se pongan el archivo para descargarlo o verlo.

así me lo muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para mostrar los mensajes uso una funcion con ajax y jquery, donde le paso el id, del chat que quiero.

```
function Seguimientos(id) {

    document.getElementById("mensajes").innerHTML = "";

    const format1 = "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"

    console.log('seguimientos');
    showSpinner();

    var URL = '/SolicitudSeguimientos/SeguimientosPorSolicitudId' + '/' + id;
    console.log('url ' + URL);
    var card = "";
    $.getJSON({
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //var d = (JSON.parse(data));
            console.log(data);

            $.each(data.seguimientos, function (i, o) {
                //@*if (o.Correo == '@(User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("#") + 1))') {*@

                    card += "<div class='direct-chat-msg'>";
                    card += "<div class='direct-chat-infos clearfix'>";
                    card += "<span class='direct-chat-name float-left'>"

                    if (o.AgenteId != 0) {
                        card += o.Agente.Nombre;
                    }
                    else {
                        card += o.Contacto.Nombre;
                        //console.log('ContactoId: ' + o.ContactoId);
                        //console.log('Contacto: ' + o.Contacto.Nombre);
                    }
                    card += "</span>";
                    card += "<span class='direct-chat-timestamp float-right'>" + moment(o.Fecha).format(format1) + "</span>";
                    card += "</div>";
                    if (o.Mensaje == null) {
                        card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'></div>";
                    }
                    else {
                        card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'>" + o.Mensaje.replaceAll("\n", "<br>") +     
                        "</div>";
                    }

                    if (o.Mensaje != null || o.Archivos != undefined) {
                        card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'>" + o.Archivos + "</div>";
                    }
                    card += "</div>";
                    
                });
                var parser = new DOMParser;
                var dom = parser.parseFromString(card, 'text/html');

                if (card.length > 0) {
                    document.getElementById("mensajes").innerHTML = card;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("mensajes").innerHTML = "<h1>No hay seguimientos</h1>";
                }

            },

                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('error');
                    hideSpinner();
                }
        })
}
```

Comment: card += "<div class='direct-chat-text'><a href='o.urlArchivos' >" + o.Archivos + "</a></div>"; esto?

Comment: sí, algo así pero ya que el archivo este guardado, que al darle click se pueda descargar

Comment: `al darle click se pueda descargar`, ¿qué características tiene un archivo  `descargable`?

Comment: Ya sea una imagen o un archivo, si lo tengo en una carpeta que se descagué